# App crashes when using Image Picker in iOS 17

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios17, xcode15

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9adf0f1f19a13e73'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x194fc25e0 0x18d2cfc00 0x195052eec 0x194f077a8 0x195048860 0x1b122e114 0x19ce03300 0x19ce04b3c 0x1b11eb02c 0x1b122c714 0x19ce03300 0x19ce04b3c 0x1b11dc2c8 0x1b124d27c 0x1b11cebf0 0x1b11ce620 0x1b1225f40 0x1faacdafc 0x1fa94c494 0x1faacda70 0x1faa0ec94 0x1fa94bd98 0x1fa94b8b8 0x1fa94b3dc 0x1fa94b46c 0x1fa94b46c 0x1fa94af5c 0x1ac82ae6c 0x19ce016a8 0x19ce03300 0x19ce0a894 0x19ce0b3c4 0x19ce16004 0x19ce15878 0x1fe0c2964 0x1fe0c2a04)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
Unknown chipRevisionID (0xffffffff)
Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).

need your support , its work fine on ios devices with version less than 17

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question to add code for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

having same issues for day now, mine is not showing any error just straight up crash, and the crash report is just showing "AVFCapture: __47+[AVCaptureDevice isEligibleForReactionEffects]_block_invoke + 196"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following keys to your Info.plist file, located in `<project root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist:`

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs permission for the photo library. This is called Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in the visual editor.

`NSCameraUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the camera. This is called Privacy - Camera Usage Description in the visual editor.

`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the microphone, if you intend to record videos. This is called Privacy - Microphone Usage Description in the visual editor.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs camera access to scan QR codes</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need microphone access for uploading audio</string>
```